# FB.api() calls inside underscore template

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook-javascript-sdk, underscore.js

The underscore template documentation suggest the following should be possible, yet it is not working for me. Executing the template simply returns nothing for this.

```
<% FB.api('/me', function(response){ %>
<%= response.name %>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: I don’t know underscore, but if this code does what I think it does – put out the value of a variable called response.name while parsing the template, then I don’t see how this should ever work. FB.api is not executed at this time.

Comment: @CBroe: Yeah, the code does do what you think it does (and at the times that you think as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a perfectly valid template; in fact, the compiled JavaScript version looks like this (reformatted for readability):

```
function(obj) {
    var __p = '';
    var print = function() { __p += Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, '') };
    with(obj || {}) {
        __p += '\n';
        FB.api('/me', function(response) { 
            __p += '\n' + response.name + '\n';
        }); 
        __p += '\n';
    }
    return __p;
}
```

And there's nothing wrong with that. BTW, you can look at the `source` attribute of a compiled Underscore template if you want to see the JavaScript for the template:

```
var t = _.template(raw_template);
console.log(t.source);
```

However, it won't do what you're expecting it to do. Your problem is that the `FB.api` call is an AJAX call and **A** stands for asynchronous. So by the time your callback gets called (i.e. `<%= response.name %>` is executed), the template will have been converted to HTML and added to the DOM and nothing will be looking at the `__p` variable anymore. The sequence looks something like this:

1. Compile the template and call the compiled template function.
2. `FB.api` gets called.
3. The template function returns some HTML.
4. The HTML from **3** is added to the DOM.
5. Time passes.
6. Facebook responds and your `FB.api` callback gets called.
7. `response.name` is appended to the `__p` buffer.

You're going to have to turn your logic inside out a bit. Your `FB.api` call should be outside your template:

```
var t = _.template(...);
FB.api('/mu', function(response) {
    var html = t({ response: response });
    // Somehow add html to the DOM
});
```

so that you don't try to use the template until all the data is ready.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Makes perfect sense.